# How do you get the achievements for the new Frontier DLC

Tags: xbox-one, titanfall

I've won several matches on Dig Site, Export and Haven, but haven't received any XBone achievements for them.

My player stats shows that I have victories on all these maps, and XBone smart glass is showing them as 100% complete but not awarded.

Is there some special extra criteria I need to pass? Those victories include some MVPs.

Is this a big on the XBone version and if so is there any way around it?

Comment: The acheivement services did go down over the last few days; if they've not unlocked in a few days, contact support.

Comment: @peper757 they have now unlocked, 8 days after I achieved them, but backdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check that you have won the achievements locally in your achievement application. Achievements that have unlocked will show there. Depending on your settings a notification may or may not have popped up.

If the achievement shows as locked there, you haven't met the requirements. If it shows as unlocked but you were not awarded with it on your profile then Live hasn't registered it yet. This may be due to Live having issues (currently the case) or due to synchronisation issues which crop up from time to time.

Due to the latter, people have reported achievements unlocking many hours or even days after unlocking them locally. If you unlocked them locally but don't want to wait, contact support. I recommend [chat support](https://support.xbox.com/contact-us) (Make choices until you get to the third step and choose chat support) as they are quite quick an can help you immediately.

Comment: I have met the requirements - that's my point. According to the in game stats I have won many matches on the relevant maps. Other achievements unlocked before and after the broken ones have unlocked, and I was playing Titanfall - an online-only game. Something has definitely synced as smartglass shows the achievements as 100% complete but locked. I have reported this in the xbone feedback app, how do you get chat support?

Comment: It does indeed sound like a synching issue. You can get chat support by this link: https://support.xbox.com/contact-us